# Laravel count categories join

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have three tables that I need to ultimately query from, and I am looking for the most efficient way of going about it.

The tables are: products, product_colors, and categories.

The relationships are products.category_id => categories.id and product_colors.product_id => products.id (filtered by product_colors.color_id)

First I have a product table, and that product has a one to many relationship with a color table, so I need to filter that based on the color.
Second, I need to filter it by the category, and return the amount of products in each category it fits.

I have the following query which will ultimately count the products in each of the categories that I want, but it doesn't filter based on the first filter of colors.

```
SELECT categories.name, SUM(IF(category_id IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS categories         
FROM products     JOIN categories ON (categories.id = products.category_id) 
WHERE(products.gender = 1)     GROUP BY categories.id;
```

I'm not too familiar with what is efficient or not in terms of queries or joins, but what I was thinking of maybe getting a list of product IDs which match the color being filtered, and then somehow doing a join on just those IDs.

Edit: in my answer below, I've come up with a solution, but it is using DB:raw -- is there any way around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to come up with the following query that will effectively return what I need, with the option of sorting by gender as well.

```
mysql> SELECT categories.name, SUM(IF(category_id IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS 
categories FROM products LEFT JOIN product_colors ON 
(product_colors.product_id = products.id) LEFT OUTER JOIN categories 
ON (categories.id = products.category_id) WHERE(products.gender = 1 AND 
product_colors.color_id = 1) GROUP BY categories.id;


+--------------+------------+
| name         | categories |
+--------------+------------+
| トップス     |         35 |
| アウター     |          1 |
| ボトムス     |          7 |
| シューズ     |         21 |
| 帽子         |          2 |
+--------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Edit: I've rewritten in it Eloquent.

```
$categories = Category::select('categories.name',DB::raw('SUM(IF(category_id     IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS categories'))
        ->join('products','categories.id','=','products.category_id')
        ->join('product_colors','product_colors.product_id','=','products.id','left outer')
        ->where('products.gender','=',1)
        ->where('product_colors.color_id','=',1)
        ->groupBy('categories.id')
        ->get();
```

The solution over all I feel isn't too bad, but I don't like the fact it is using DB:raw. If anyone has an alternative to that, I would appreciate it.